# IPv6 (aiccu tunneled) server consistently resolves addresses to its own IPv6 address

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, tunneling

I have a Fedora 10 server using an IPv6 tunnel broker (sixxs).  One of the nagging things I have noticed is that using any common utilities like "wget" domains resolve to the real IPv4 destination address AND MY OWN IPv6 address.  The utility then tries to connect to the IPv6 address (my own) and gets a 404, forcing something like "wget -4" resolves this and it connects to the real destination but I have a feeling its not supposed to be this broken in the first place.

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:21:13:14:C0  
          inet addr:XXX.129.227.207  Bcast:XXX.129.227.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::XXX:21ff:fe13:14c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1502991032 errors:0 dropped:7243 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1496098078 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:3962471373 (3.6 GiB)  TX bytes:1826394384 (1.7 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:9776357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9776357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:482344853 (459.9 MiB)  TX bytes:482344853 (459.9 MiB)

sixxs     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet6 addr: 2a01:XXX:6:1e0::2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80:XXX:6:1e0:2/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:15199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:2584878 (2.4 MiB)  TX bytes:1531185 (1.4 MiB)
```

And an example of it happening:

```
[hudson@devbox ~]$ wget "http://hudson-ci.org/latest/hudson.war"
--2010-11-17 10:45:56--  http://hudson-ci.org/latest/hudson.war
Resolving hudson-ci.org... 2a01:XXX:6:1e0::2, 192.18.49.133
Connecting to hudson-ci.org|2a01:XXX:6:1e0::2|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2010-11-17 10:45:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.

[hudson@devbox ~]$ wget -4 "http://hudson-ci.org/latest/hudson.war"
--2010-11-17 10:46:13--  http://hudson-ci.org/latest/hudson.war
Resolving hudson-ci.org... 192.18.49.133
Connecting to hudson-ci.org|192.18.49.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 30672930 (29M) [text/plain]
Saving to: `hudson.war'

100%[======================================================================================================================>] 30,672,930  76.1K/s   in 70s     

2010-11-17 10:47:25 (431 KB/s) - `hudson.war' saved [30672930/30672930]
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your DNS search path in /etc/resolv.conf and most likely you have a wildcard AAAA record for the search path itself, as such it will resolve everything from that

Comment: doh, there was no search path in /etc/resolv.conf ... setting one fixed the problem!